# building docker image using a remote docker file in github using python sdk

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pygithub, python-docker

I am able to build docker image using python sdk. if the dockerfile is available on my local machine.

```
client = docker.from_env()
image, build_log = client.images.build(path = "./", tag=image_name,rm=True)
```

Now, My docker files will be maintained in github repository, I should pull them and build the images.
python sdk doc says build method accepts path or file objects.

I was able to read the content of the docker file from github using pyGithub (API3)  repository

```
g = Github(base_url=url, login_or_token=accessToken, verify=False)
dmc = g.get_organization(org_name)
repo = dmc.get_repo(repoName)
contents = repo.get_contents(dockerfile_name, "master")
```

I am not sure how to convert above contents object(ContentFile.ContentFile) to a python file object so that I can use it to build the image as below

```
client = docker.from_env()
image, build_log = client.images.build(fileobj = contents_file_obj, tag=image_name,rm=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below working piece of code can be used to bring out Python file obj from `ContentFile.ContentFile`:

```py
import io
from github import Github 
import docker

# docker client
client = docker.from_env()

# github repo
g = Github(base_url=url, login_or_token=accessToken, verify=False)
dmc = g.get_organization(org_name)
repo = dmc.get_repo(repoName)
contents = repo.get_contents(dockerfile_name, "master")

# decoding contents of file and creating file obj out of it
decoded_content_str = contents.decoded_content.decode('utf-8')
contents_file_obj = io.StringIO(decoded_content_str)

# building image out of contents file obj
client = docker.from_env()
image, build_log = client.images.build(
                       fileobj=contents_file_obj,
                       tag=image_name,
                       rm=True)
```

In above code, 
method `decoded_content` of `contents` (obj of class `ContentFile.ContentFile`) returns byte string content of file.
which decoded into string by `.decode('utf-8')`.

then `decoded_content_str` is used to create IO object (same as file object in python) using `io.StringIO`

Comment: okay. I've modified answer for better visibility of issue.

Comment: @Tomerikoo  can you please remove downvote from my answer as it banned my account from answering and questioning.

Comment: I didn't downvote... Please see [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post). Please also note that your answer is still a bit lacking... Try to show a bit of context, how exactly to use this `.content()` property

Comment: hi @Tomerikoo, firstly, thanks for helping out what need to be shown in ideal answer.  I've added tested code which answers the question and this time I've added some more research and tested locally before re-editing my answer.

Comment: I'm happy to see you took the bother to improve your answer as needed. By the way, if you have some link to a resource that helped you write this answer, it is ok to post it - the problem before was that you completely relied on that link. You can post a link as a reference for further reading to support your answer

Comment: yes. I'll make sure to be more resourceful and descriptive before contributing. Thanks again. :)